# Navbar with navwalker plugin does not collapse submenus correctly

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am currently having trouble with the collapsing navbar for mobile devices for my website: www.pctbu.com

When I minimize the window to adjust for mobile browsers, and click on a dropdown option in the navbar, the submenu that pops up does not extend the navbar like I want it to. Instead, it opens up exactly like it does on the desktop version of my site.

I have used the navwalker class in my functions.php file, and it looks like this:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'menu' => 'header-menu',
        'menu_class' => 'nav nav-pills nav-justified navbar-inverse',
        'container' => 'false',
        'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()
    );
    wp_nav_menu ( $args );
?>
```

I am not sure if this is a known issue, but I have searched around, and some people say it might be a problem with versions of wordpress higher than 2.

If anyone could steer me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: no, this shouldn't happen and I build tens of custom WP sites using nav-walker per month, so I'm 100% sure it's an error somewhere and has nothing to do with BS2 or BS3, but hard to tell without seeing the site (as a matter of fact I don't quite understand the exact problem without). If you could provide a link, I'll take a look

Comment: pctbu.com is the website. I don't know why it didn't show up in the original post. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found the problem. Add this to your CSS stylesheet

```
@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 780px) {
.dropdown-menu {
position: relative;
top: 100%;
left: 0px;
z-index: 1000;
display: none;
float: none;
min-width: 160px;
padding: 5px 0px;
margin: 2px 0px 0px;
font-size: 14px;
text-align: left;
list-style: none outside none;
background-color: #FFF;
background-clip: padding-box;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
border-radius: 4px;
box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.176);
}
}
```

This will fix this ONLY for small tablets and smaller mobiles, yet keeping your current styles for desktop